# debugging my local dev environment and half my page is loading

Tags: magento, debugging, vagrant, localhost

This is really frustrating and I've been following all my error messages and fixing them until this last one... i'm not sure what this one means.

My error report message is saying:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:2940:"SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu`, IFNULL(url_rewrite.request_path, default_ur.request_path) AS `request_path` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1)
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite_category` ON url_rewrite_category.category_id = e.entity_id AND url_rewrite_category.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite_category.url_rewrite_id = url_rewrite.url_rewrite_id AND url_rewrite.is_system = 1
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite` AS `default_urc` ON default_urc.category_id = e.entity_id AND default_urc.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_url_rewrite` AS `default_ur` ON default_ur.url_rewrite_id = default_urc.url_rewrite_id AND default_ur.is_system = 1 WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '145')) AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1')

";i:1;s:5945:"#0 /vagrant/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /vagrant/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /vagrant/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /vagrant/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#4 /vagrant/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#5 /vagrant/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#6 /vagrant/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#7 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1047): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, I...')
#8 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php(225): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load(false, false)
#10 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php(168): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection->load()
#11 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php(576): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree->addCollectionData(NULL, false, '2', true, true)
#12 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php(818): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category->getCategories('2', 0, false, false, true)
#13 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php(82): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category->getCategories('2', 0, false, false, true)
#14 /vagrant/app/code/local/webs/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(13): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category->getStoreCategories()
#15 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): webs_Catalog_Model_Observer->addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(webs_Catalog_Model_Observer), 'addCatalogToTop...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 /vagrant/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#18 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#19 /vagrant/app/design/frontend/enterprise/webs/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(34): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
#20 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/vagrant/app/de...')
#21 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#22 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', false)
#28 /vagrant/app/design/frontend/enterprise/webs/template/page/html/header.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu', false)
#29 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/vagrant/app/de...')
#30 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#31 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#34 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#35 /vagrant/app/design/frontend/enterprise/webs/template/page/1column.phtml(41): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#36 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/vagrant/app/de...')
#37 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#38 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#39 /vagrant/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#40 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#41 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#42 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#43 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#44 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#45 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#46 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#47 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#48 /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#49 /vagrant/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#50 /vagrant/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#51 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Looks like there is a conflict inside one of the url_rewrite tables??

I tried to truncate them but still nothing.

Comment: do you have any customization related to redirect or URL.#14 /vagrant/app/code/local/webs/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(13): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category->getStoreCategories()  See this line. You will find what's goind wrong here.

Comment: @Kul yes i do.. i'll have a look... do you suggest removing it for now?

Comment: Yes. You can remove this observer from app/code/local/webs Module. You can see list on event and just comment event which use this observer

Comment: Do you typically ignore all the core modules and look to identify anything in the local first and remove it? I'll try this now by the way.

Comment: What made you identify #14 from that list? Because it was the first local module? Curious

Comment: HI @thismethod Ofcourse , becuase its local Module. see error report. If have not modified core file rhere is less chance to get core error, Second thing module also looks related to your error. Now you can see if error is come from there or not.